# Make a bash function to zip folder(s)

Tags: bash, zip

The problem is that when I try to run the bash function, the terminal gets stuck and nothing happens.

I would like to make zipping folders faster so I though of making an alias.

I would like to type: zip folder1 ,and a folder1.zip to be created.

I would also like if I could do this with multiple folders in one go: zip folder1 folder2 folder3 ,and their zips to be created.

I added:

```
zip() {

zip "$1.zip" "$1" -rvZ store

}
```

in the `.bashrc`, after which I tried zipping a folder from the terminal: zip folder1

The expected result would be folder1.zip is created, in which there are file1 file2 file3.

Comment: Since you've replaced the standard `zip` command with a function, when the function runs `zip` it runs the function again, which runs the function again, which... Solution: use a different name for your function. Replacing standard commands with nonstandard variants like this tends to cause problems, so *don't*.

Comment: You're calling the `zip` function recursively, which will cause the `bash` to crash. Use `command zip` inside the function body, instead of bare `zip`.

Answer (score -1):

This is what I use as my alias.
`alias bkprt='tar --exclude=t.zip -czvf t.zip /root/'`
It won’t accept variables, but works.

Make an alias for this bash script seems to work, although it uses tar.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n "Folder to zip:";read a
echo -n "Zip name:";read b
tar -czvf $b.zip $a;
```